# No Metadata Classes to process

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I use for updating the schema `doctrine:schema:update`

Error:

> No Metadata Classes to process.

Here is my Entity code:

```
namespace Esprit\ParcBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* Class Modele
* @package ParcBundle\Entity
*
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="Modele")
*/
class Modele{
/**
 *@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="Auto")
 *@ORM\Id
 *@ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
 private $id;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=255)
 *
 */

private $Libelle;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=255)
 */

private $Pays;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=255)
 */

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getLibelle()
{
    return $this->Libelle;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $Libelle
 */
public function setLibelle($Libelle)
{
    $this->Libelle = $Libelle;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $id
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getPays()
{
    return $this->Pays;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $Pays
 */
public function setPays($Pays)
{
    $this->Pays = $Pays;
}
}
```

Here is my `appkernel.php` file:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
public function registerBundles()
        {
        $bundles = [
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
        new ParcBundle\ParcBundle(),
];




if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
    }

    return $bundles;
}

public function getRootDir()
{
    return __DIR__;
}

public function getCacheDir()
{
    return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/'.$this->getEnvironment();
}

public function getLogDir()
{
    return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/logs';
}

public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
{
    $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
}
}
```

Comment: did you forgot to import the `ORM` namespace?

Comment: thanks for your answer but no

Comment: namespace Esprit\ParcBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

Comment: have you cleared your (prod and dev) cache?

Comment: how i do that ?

Comment: `php app/console cache:clear`

Comment: no same problem :/

Comment: let's see your `AppKernel.php` file.

Comment: i didn't do any modification on it

Comment: is the `ParcBundle` bundle registered?

Comment: yep i created the base but it came with that error with the updating of the schema

Comment: is the namespace `ParcBundle\ParcBundle` instead of `Esprit\ParcBundle\ParcBundle`?

Comment: yep it's Esprit/ParcBundle^Entity , 
but it should named like this right? (nameOfProject\nameOfBundle\folderOfTheEntity )

Comment: If `new ParcBundle\ParcBundle()` is correct and you're using a conventional bundle structure, then you need to change `namespace Esprit\ParcBundle\Entity;` to `namespace ParcBundle\Entity;`. That's how an autoload-psr-4-compatible works

Comment: i used to declare bundles ans it work , 
but i changed the namespace to ParcBundle and i got this error 
[Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]                                                                    
  [Enum Error] Attribute "strategy" of @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\GeneratedValue declared on property ParcBundle\Entity\Mo  
  dele::$id accept only [AUTO, SEQUENCE, TABLE, IDENTITY, NONE, UUID, CUSTOM], but got Auto.

Comment: `AUTO` !== `Auto`

Comment: i fixed the problems and it worked